# Django extending user with custom and order of fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have extended User module with new fields in module.py.

```
class Coach(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User);
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100);
    address2=models.CharField(max_length=100);
    zip= models.CharField(max_length=5);
    city= models.CharField(max_length=100);
    canton= models.CharField(max_length=50);
    country= models.CharField(max_length=50);
    prefix=models.CharField(max_length=5);
    telephone=models.CharField(max_length=30);
    language=models.CharField(max_length=20);

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Coach.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

and I added this to connect user model with new fields from coach in admin.py:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Coach
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines =[ UserProfileInline, ]

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

My problem is order of the displayed fields in User model in Admin. Picture below shows current state, the group ('profile') new added field are on top of page first picture:
http://www.dodaj.rs/f/1v/3c/1brWQwyO/change-order.png

This is what I would like to have:
http://www.dodaj.rs/f/3f/10J/25qz2FSW/change-order2.jpg

Comment: I am not sure, has been some time since i worked witbh admin. But at least you can set the field order. How to replace the Profile bar im not sure.
Not very useful but might get you started in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

I have found a way, I just modify template. By default admin/template/change_form.html has order to display first fields in inline_field_sets, then field_sets.

I just changed order, I have set to render field_sets first, after that inline_field_sets.

```
    {% block field_sets %}
    {% for fieldset in adminform %}
        {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block inline_field_sets %}
    {% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}
        {% include inline_admin_formset.opts.template %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
        ('', {
            'fields': ('password', 'last_login', 'groups', 'more_fields...',),
        }),
    )
    inlines =[ UserProfileInline, ]
```

Comment: Problem is same, with adding custom field from User I just have some of fields I don't want that. First render inline than fieldsets, I want reverse order. I can't put field from extended user (Coach) to fieldsets, that would be the easiest way, but this not allowed me to do.

Comment: U should create an admin  class for Coach with inline representing the USER model